# Joda HIbernate - Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

I'd like to have a compound field - lastLogin and a separate field - timeZone. 
I want to be able to insert the complex object - lastLogin (containing the timeZone) and the timeZone as a standalone field at the same time to the database.

With the following code though:

```
@Columns(columns = {@Column(name = "LastLogin_TS"), @Column(name = "LOCAL_TS_TZ", updatable = false, insertable = false)})
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone")
private DateTime lastLogin;

@Column(name = "LOCAL_TS_TZ")
private DateTimeZone timeZone;
```

I am getting the obvious:

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.myPkg.MyClass column: LOCAL_TS_TZ (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Is there a way to somehow join those columns (lastLogin and timeZone) instead of specifying a column with the @Column annotation?

**UPDATE:**
I set up the insertable and updatable properties of the LOCAL_TS_TZ column to false as suggested but I ran into another problem now:

> Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed: lastLogin

Answer (score 1):

You should add `insertable = false, updatable = false` to one of your fields because you have mapping to the same column.
Like:

```
@Column(name = "LOCAL_TS_TZ", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private DateTimeZone timeZone;
```

If you need to create custom type you can do it [this way](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom-type).

Comment: Cheers for your suggestion. I tried setting insertable and updatable to false as suggested by the stacktrace and you but here is the contradiction now: "Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed: lastLogin"